# Which loop do i need if i want to sth until there are no more childnodes within a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Whats the best "loop" if i want to move  child nodes 1 by 1 from one div to others. At the end there are no more img's left in the div (#load), so i thought i can use

```
do { ... } while ($('#load img')!=0);
```

I sort the `img` elements into 3 `div` elements depending on the width of each `div`.

Which loop would be the best? And how?

Comment: You'd need to test the `.length` of the jQuery object returned, but don't do that. Too expensive. Just do the DOM selection once outside the loop. Are all your elements going to the same location?

Comment: Why do you need to use a loop?

Comment: I sort the img's into 3 divs depending on the div's width.

http://easy.sirius.uberspace.de/fotografie.html

it already "works" more or less with a for loop with the length, but i need settimeout or it is to slow :s  Sry i am very new i am learning atm from zero by building my page.

Comment: Better to learn by reading tutorials. You'll learn most of the basic patterns to use with jQuery.

Comment: by reading tutorials i forget the most, learning by doing is better (for me), and mostly i find soulutions by my own research, but this time not, sry dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each()` of jquery for that

```
$('#load img').each(function (index) {
  if(index==n)
   { 
      //do something here
      }
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: and if the intention is to reverse you can do `$($("#load img").get().reverse()).each(...`